# In R, how to correctly classify 0-1 variables as factor variable?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that makes a summary of all variables in my data frame. The data frame has 468 variables and 274 observations.

The variables in my data frame are of type integer and factor(categorical)

Some of the categorical variables have 0-1 values and when I try to find the class of these variables using `lapply` I get the output as integer. What function should I use to treat these variables as categorical?

I am using the following syntax to find the class of all variables.

```
class_list <- lapply(dataset,class)
```

Comment: You can use `factor()` or `as.factor()`, but in most modeling applications there is no practical difference between a binary integer variable coded as 0-1 and a binary categorical variable.

Comment: Thank you Gregor!! But are you suggesting that I do it manually? Because the number of variables in my data frame is 478 and it would be to time consuming to iterate through each subset of these variables.

Comment: No, by saying "*in most modeling applications there is no practical difference between a binary integer variable coded as 0-1 and a binary categorical variable*" I'm suggesting that you don't do it all. If you really want to do it still, then of course you shouldn't do it manually - use a `for` loop or `lapply`. Write a test to figure out if you want to convert a column, then `my_data[cols_to_convert] = lapply(my_data[cols_to_convert], as.factor).

Comment: Ok!! I will try that and see how it works. Thank you.

Comment: Hey thanx Gregor!! I used a for loop with as.factor and it worked out pretty well.